# how can i make my html elements of a website fit to mobile screen (320px)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

[this is my site with bootstrap it shows the content very small in the screen left corner , how can i fit that to the mobile screen .](http://kanakkids.com/)

So Far i have done some media queries

```
@media screen and (max-width:360px){

.navbar-brand a > img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -23px;
    left: -10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 4px #000;
    height: 87px;
}

.navbar-toggle {

    padding: 16px 10px;

}

.navbar-toggle:hover {
    color:#fff;

}

.navbar-right {
    float: right !important;
    margin-right: -42px;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    left: -103px;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
    border-color: transparent;

}
```